# How to say "Yes, I'm still interested in this"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, sentence-structure

Seems pretty easy, but I don't know to say something that basic. It should be something like "mich interessiert", but I'm answering to an email here and I want to make it not rude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, ich bin immer noch interessiert.

Ja, ich habe immer noch Interesse an XXX.